# iOS - Check for Navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm creating a library which will add a view at the bottom of the application (when my library is integrated in application).
I'm using view controller's view's frame parameter to get the size of the view and calculation my library's view frame according and showing it.
The problem is that when navigation bar is there, my view is going still below the actual view visible. So, i want to know whether current view controller is based on navigation controller or not and whether navigation bar is visible in that view or not. how can I find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` inherits from and has all the fine properties and behaviors of `UIView` and one of these properties is [`hidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden).

So for your view, if you can get a handle to your navigation bar, all you need to do is check to see if `hidden` is `YES` or `NO`.

one way to do this would be to have a UINavigationController property or accessor (setter & getter) for your library so whoever makes use of the library can set the navigation controller and/or bar on your library's behalf.

Comment: I know the properties of navigation bar. But how to check if the app is based on navigation controller or not? If the app is based on navigation controller, I can check the properties of navigation bar. Isn't it?

Comment: How can I get the handle to navigation bar?

Comment: if you have a navigation controller in one of your view controllers or your application delegate, make sure it's an IBOutlet and then you can get at the navigation bar via [`UINavigationController`'s navigationBar property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBar) (documentation linked for you)

Comment: I'm creating a library. When the developers integrate my library in their application, i want to find whether the application has navigation bar or not. I know the methods available in iOS library to check for navigation bar.

Comment: one way to do this would be to have a `UINavigationController` property or accessor (setter & getter) for your library so whoever makes use of the library can set the navigation controller and/or bar on your library's behalf.

Comment: I'm doing the same now. I thought there might be some other solution than this..... anyway,thanks for providing the info

Answer (score 11):

I'm late with the reply, but for other persons who try to do the same thing (like me :D).

This code may solve your problem:

```
id nav = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
if ([nav isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController *navc = (UINavigationController *) nav;
    if(navc.navigationBarHidden) {
        NSLog(@"NOOOO NAV BAR");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"WE HAVE NAV BAR");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been using this snippet for a long time with much success (thank you). I have recently found a shortfall though. If a UIAlertView is currently visible this function will fail. Further investigation revealed the following upon execution: `(lldb) po nav
<_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController: 0x7fa00d095fb0>` Do you have a suggestion for handling this case?

Comment: @alexgophermix i think you can use windows propery array from UIApplication and find your root controller, i think in that moment you are going to have 2 windows there.

Comment: @CornelDamian thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it out :)

Comment: it works fine for me, even try to access from library,you saves my time

Answer (score 0):

Up to date check from a view controller context:

```
    let navHidden = navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden ?? true
    if needsCloseButton || navHidden
    {
         // here add an alternative ways to get out since back button is not here, say add a close button somewhere
```

Comment: This question is some years old and the provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.